# $L^2$ equality implies $L^1$ equality or a.e. equality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f\in L^1 \cap L^2$ and $g\in L^2$.

If I know that $f=g$ in $L^2$, then does it follow that $f=g$ in $L^1$ or a.e?

Does it follow that $g\in L^1$?

More generally, if $f\in L^s \cap L^r, g\in L^s$ and $f=g$ in $L^s$, then does it follow that $g\in L^r$?

In particular, I have the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ in mind but I am also curious about general results.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: For any measure $\mu$: equality of $f,g$ in any $L^p(\mu)$ space is $\mu$-a.e. equality of $f,g$.  That's all there is to it

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Oh yeah.. it's easy as that. I'm such a fool.... Thank you.